# Google Dialer permanent search widget on ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm currently implementing an Android app and wanted to know if there are any library out there to create a permanent search widget on the ActionBar, like the Google Dialer one and like this picture:

[Google Dialer ActionBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lvcb1.png)

I don't want to start implementing my own if there is a library out there than can do it for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like floatingsearchview:

https://github.com/arimorty/floatingsearchview